# Autocomplete doesn't fire select() on click element from list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery 1.4.4 and jquery-ui 1.8.24. I have a dialog, and inside that dialog a link. After clicking on that link, i show user an input with an autocomplete. When user select an item from autocomplete list and hits enter key, everything works fine. Unfortunatelly, when user manualy click on the item from autocomplete list, the event "select" doesn't get called at all and dialog closes itself instantly.

Also, i'm using a lot of live() and die() to prevent binding multiple events to my DOM elements.

```
$j("#" + id + "_selector:not(.ui-autocomplete-input)").die().live("focus", function (event) {

        $j(this).autocomplete({
            autoFocus:true,
            html:true,
            create:function() {
               // this always invokes
               console.log('autocomplete created');
            },
            source:function (request, response) {
                var term = request.term;
                if (term in cache) {
                    response(cache[term]);
                    return;
                }

                request.kind = settings.kind
                request.no_email_display = settings.no_email_display

                lastXhr = $j.getJSON(Routes.search_account_path().url, request, function (data, status, xhr) {
                    cache[ term ] = data;
                    if (xhr === lastXhr) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                    // this one works only after selecting by keyboard and hitting entery key
                    var origEvent = event;
                    while (origEvent.originalEvent !== undefined)
                        origEvent = origEvent.originalEvent;
                    console.log(origEvent);                        
                },

        });
    });
```

What I'm suspecting is dialog somehow takeover click event from my autocomplete.

I'll be vary happy if anyone could help me how to at least debug this error (tools?how to setup firebug, breakpoints etc?), because I realize this bug may be almost impossible to reproduce.

Comment: Could you do a jsfiddle? also, instead of using die and live, you could use .one() which only binds it once.